# How to extract the number of installations for each app on the GitHub marketplace?

Tags: github, scrape, marketplace

I have an issue, in a project, I’ve been asked to extract the number of installations for each app on the GitHub marketplace. I wrote the code to scrape data from the marketplace website but there are no stats (including the number of installations) for apps. Can someone help me through this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look at https://ghtorrent.org/  or one of multiple derived datasets.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I downloaded the Daily dumps of 2019-06-30, and I could not find anything about the number of installations of apps in it. Can you give me some hints on how to find that, please? do you know if there are some information about apps in these files? @fukanchik